# Datatable to XML based on dynamic coumns

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert a datatable to XML.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732223/To-Generate-XML-File-from-Datatable-using-LINQ

Above link mentions how to do this for a table with known columns. Is there a way to do this when the columns are dynamic (not hardcoded in LINQ.?

```
 string s=  new XElement("Employees",
                 from empList in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 orderby empList.Field<decimal>("ESalary") descending
                 select new XElement("Employee",
                      new XAttribute("EmployeeId", empList.Field<Int32>("EID")),
                      new XAttribute("Salary", empList.Field<decimal>("ESalary")),
                      new XElement("EmployeeName", empList.Field<string>("EName")),
                      new XElement("Designation", empList.Field<string>("EDesignation"))
                 )).ToString() 
            }
```

Here Emp, EmpID, salary, etc are hardcoded. I want this to work for all tables is there a way in LINQ?

I am trying like:

```
   XElement cust = new XElement("TEST",
        from str in table.AsEnumerable()
        let fields = (from dr in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                         select dr.ItemArray)
        select new XElement("Client", splitTempalte.Zip(fields, (name, value) => new XElement(name, value)))
    );
```

If there is no option then I wil have to use for loop for each row, within this another for loop for each column and use the LINQ zip. Just looking to see if there is better way then this using datatable to LINQ (with dynamic columns).